# yocto how to add a error handler for a specified task?

Tags: yocto

I want to add a error handler for do_image_* tasks of core-image-minimal(e.g., when do_image_* failed, execute my handler).

I tried `bb.build.TaskFailed`, but it seems to be for all tasks. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that works. If there are other more suitable solutions, please let me know, thank you. Everyone is welcome to discuss.

I use the `bb.build.TaskFailed` event, although it's global, not specific to a recipe. In the handler body, I use e.getTask() to determine whether the specified task failed, and if so, execute my code.

```
addhandler cjlhandler
python cjlhandler() {
    bb.warn("TaskName is %s" % e.getTask())
    # you should add if statement to determine whether the specified task failed
}
cjlhandler[eventmask] = "bb.build.TaskFailed"
```